# Загрузка ReportDocument с потока

Tags: c#

У меня есть поток с отчетом CrystalReports. Мне нужно отобразить отчет в ReportViewer'e.
Вот код експорта в поток:

```
ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
doc.Load(@"" + Address.Text);
doc.SetDatabaseLogon(log_in.Text, password.Text);
MemoryStream stream;
stream = (MemoryStream)doc.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.CrystalReport);
```

При получении потока я конвертирую его в byte array:

```
byte[] reportPDF = stream.ToArray();
document.Load("test.rpt"); //пустой отчет для отображения в него информации
document.SetDataSource(reportPDF); //Вылетает исключение, что здесь нет таблиц
this.reportView.ReportSource = document;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему сам. Думал есть какой-то метод из стандартных инструментов, но не нашел. Пришлось писать в файл данные с потока и открывать уже готовый файл. Другого ответа пока не нашел:

```
 public Form1(MemoryStream report, string login, string password)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReportDocument document = new ReportDocument();
            try
            {
                byte[] reportArray = report.ToArray();
                Stream output = new FileStream("./temp.rpt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                output.Write(reportArray, 0, reportArray.Length);
                document.Load("./temp.rpt");
                output.Close();
                loadReport(document, login, password);
            }

        catch (CrystalReportsException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            this.Close();
        }
    }

 private void loadReport(ReportDocument doc, string login, string password)
    {
        doc.SetDatabaseLogon(login, password);
        this.reportView.ReportSource = doc;
        this.reportView.Show();
        this.Show();
    }
```